# Is there any way for animating the text (atext) in aframe [WebAR]?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, web-ar

In Web AR,I need to animate atext component in aframe. How to achieve the text animation in aframe ? Not found any properties in atext component.

Comment: You want to move the text as a whole, or letters separately?

Comment: Letters separately, is it possible using aframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no simple way to treat the letters as separate entities. They're even not separate meshes - the component generates one geometry containing all letters.

Probably it would be better to create an animated model, or even to use an animated texture.

---

However, with a little bit javascript we can dig into the underlying `THREE.js` layer and split a `text` into separate letters.

One way would be to attach `text` components with a single letters to `<a-entity>` nodes.

Having `<a-entity>` nodes declared we can attach animations like we would to a normal `a-frame` entity (especially position / rotation ones). But there comes the issue of positioning:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("splitter", {
    init: function() {
      // grab all <a-entity> letter nodes
      const letter_nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
      // grab the "text" configuration
      const textData = this.el.getAttribute("text");
      // create a temporary vector to store the position
      const vec = new THREE.Vector3();
      
      for (var i = 0; i < letter_nodes.length; i++) {
        // set the "text" component in each letter node
        letter_nodes[i].setAttribute('text', {
          value: textData.value[i],
          anchor: textData.align, // a-text binding
          width: textData.width // a-text binding
        })
        // set position
        vec.copy(this.el.getAttribute("position"));
        vec.x += i * 0.1; // move the letters to the right
        vec.y -= 0.2; // move them down
        letter_nodes[i].setAttribute("position", vec)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <!-- original text -->
  <a-text value="foo" position="0 1.6 -1" splitter></a-text>

  <!-- entities  -->
  <a-entity class="letter" animation="property: position; to: 0 1.2 -1; dur: 1000; dir: alternate; loop: true"></a-entity>
  <a-entity class="letter" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 0 360; dur: 1000; dir: alternate; loop: true"></a-entity>
  <a-entity class="letter"></a-entity>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

First of all - we need to get the original letters spacing, this is sloppy. From what I can tell, a-frames version of `THREE.TextGeometry` has a property `visibleGlyphs`, which has the position of the glyphs (as well as their heights, and offsets). We can use it to properly position our text.

Second of all - the position animation needs the global position. It would be better to input offsets, not target positions. To make it work, the text nodes could be child nodes of the `.letter` nodes.

A "generic" component could look like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("text-splitter", {
    init: function() {
      const el = this.el;
      // i'll use the child nodes as wrapper entities for letter entities
      const letter_wrappers = el.children

      // wait until the text component tells us that it's ready
      this.el.addEventListener("object3dset", function objectset(evt) {
        el.removeEventListener("object3dset", objectset); // react only once

        const mesh = el.getObject3D("text") // grab the mesh
        const geometry = mesh.geometry // grab the text geometry

        // wait until the visibleGlyphs are set
        const idx = setInterval(evt => {
          if (!geometry.visibleGlyphs) return;
          clearInterval(idx);

          // we want data.height, data.yoffset and position from each glyph
          const glyphs = geometry.visibleGlyphs

          // do as many loops as there are <entity - glyph> pairs
          const iterations = Math.min(letter_wrappers.length, glyphs.length)
          const textData = el.getAttribute("text"); // original configuration
          var text = textData.value.replace(/\s+/, "") // get rid of spaces

          const letter_pos = new THREE.Vector3();
          for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            // use the positions, heights, and offsets of the glyphs
            letter_pos.set(glyphs[i].position[0], glyphs[i].position[1], 0);
            letter_pos.y += (glyphs[i].data.height + glyphs[i].data.yoffset) / 2;

            // convert the letter local position to world
            mesh.localToWorld(letter_pos)

            // convert the world position to the <a-text> position
            el.object3D.worldToLocal(letter_pos)

            // apply the text and position to the wrappers
            const node = document.createElement("a-entity")
            node.setAttribute("position", letter_pos)
            node.setAttribute('text', {
              value: text[i],
              anchor: textData.align, // a-text binding
              width: textData.width // a-text binding
            })
            letter_wrappers[i].appendChild(node)
          }
          // remove the original text
          el.removeAttribute("text")
        }, 100)
      })
    }
  })

</script>
<a-scene>
  <!-- child entities of the original a-text are used as letter wrappers -->
  <a-text value="fo o" position="0 1.6 -1" text-splitter>
    <a-entity animation="property: rotation; to: 0 0 360; dur: 1000; loop: true"></a-entity>
    <a-entity animation="property: position; to: 0 0.25 0; dur: 500; dir: alternate; loop: true"></a-entity>
    <a-entity animation="property: position; to: 0 -0.25 0; dur: 500; dir: alternate; loop: true"></a-entity>
  </a-text>
  
  <!-- just to see that the text is aligned properly-->
  <a-text value="fo o" position="0 1.6 -1"></a-text>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

[Here's an example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/text_anime.html) of dynamically adding text entities + using anime.js to set up a timeline for each letter.

Comment: Thanks For your answer, How can we add those 'a-entity' dynamically instead of manually writing the a-entity corresponding to the characters inside atext?

Comment: Also, When we are using a space in between texts, position of letters goes wrong, How we can avoid that ?

Comment: made an update regarding spaces, I'll post a dynamic solution later today

Comment: Can we use anime.js for animating the aframe text ?

Comment: The animation component [is using anime.js](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/303e9de65068deffc5b74e0071f2da90979472b5/src/components/animation.js#L217) for animation, so `anime.js` should work as long as it's not animating `CSS` properties (maybe it could work if another component  would translate css -> 3D position)

Comment: @PranavK I've made an [example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/text_anime.html) with dynamic entity adding + an anime.js timeline